# Using <style lang="scss"> in vue component gives error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, webpack, sass, webpacker

I am trying to use vue js in rails.
Everything works, except when I tried to use `<style>` inside `.vue component`

The exact error is:

> ./app/javascript/layouts/dashboard.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss& (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--1-2!./node_modules/style-loader/dist!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--5-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-3!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./app/javascript/layouts/dashboard.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss&)
>   Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
>   SassError: Expected newline.

### My `environment.js` file

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader')

const vueLoader = require('./loaders/vueLoader')
const vuetifyLoader = require('./loaders/vuetifyLoader')

environment.plugins.prepend('VueLoaderPlugin', new VueLoaderPlugin())

environment.loaders.prepend('vue', vueLoader)

environment.loaders.prepend('vuetify', vuetifyLoader)

const resolver = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    }
  }
}

environment.config.merge(resolver)

module.exports = environment
```

### VuetifyLoader.js file

```
module.exports = {
  test: /\.s(c|a)ss$/,
  use: [
    'vue-style-loader',
    'css-loader',
    {
      loader: 'sass-loader',
      // Requires sass-loader@^7.0.0
      options: {
        implementation: require('sass'),
        fiber: require('fibers'),
        indentedSyntax: true // optional
      },
      // Requires sass-loader@^8.0.0
      options: {
        implementation: require('sass'),
        sassOptions: {
          fiber: require('fibers'),
          indentedSyntax: true // optional
        },
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

Comment: Which vuetify version do you use?

Comment: Vuetify version is 2.1.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem was with `fiber` and `indentedSyntax`. After removing those two, everything works as expected. I was getting lots of error related to scss like 
like

> expected new line

in sass files inside node_modules. I don't know, why vuetify recommends to use fiber in sass loader.

Comment: Note that when using sass (Dart Sass), synchronous compilation is twice as fast as asynchronous compilation by default, due to the overhead of asynchronous callbacks. To avoid this overhead, you can use the fibers package to call asynchronous importers from the synchronous code path.

Answer (score 6):

install these two plugins.

```
npm install --save node-sass
npm install --save sass-loader
```

Comment: I do have those plugins installed. I have solved the problem anyway. It worked after removing fiber and indentedSyntax. Thanks for answering though.

Comment: he is using dart-sass (sass) and you are recommending to install node-sass ?